# Matplotlib.hist - smoothing the line between points with step histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to smooth the line between points. Increasing the number of bins is one approach, but on my real data that still doesn't resolve the issue.

```
def plotstep_test(x, y, z):

    plt.figure(figsize=[10, 6])
    plt.hist([x, y, z], color=['red','black', 'green'], histtype='step', bins=20)

    plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
    plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')

    plt.title('', fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel('', fontsize=14, labelpad=5)
    plt.ylabel('', fontsize=14, labelpad=5)


    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1), fontsize=12)    
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', left=True, bottom=True,labelbottom=True) 


    plt.show()
```

With random numbers:

```
plotstep_test(np.random.uniform(size=10), np.random.uniform(size=5), np.random.uniform(size=50))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might prefer a [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to a histogram. Then you'll have complete control over the smoothness of the estimate.

Try [`seaborn.distplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html):

```
data = np.random.normal(size=100)
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot(data)
```

This gives you:

[image: distplot example]

If you like the look of the line, you can get the rest of your stuff working no problem I'm sure.

In general, `seaborn` makes really nice statistical plots. [Check out the gallery.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html)